# get name of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this array Json, how could I get the name of the object?
this is my array json:

```
var datos =  {"animales":[
{
    "nombre":"Lucy",
    "animal":"Cat",
    "breed":"American Shorthair",
    "note":"She raised me"
},
{
    "nombre":"Homer",
    "animal":"Cat",
    "breed":"unknown",
    "note":"Named after a world-famous bassoonist"
},
{
    "nombre":"Muchacha",
    "animal":"Dog",
        "breed":"mutt",
        "note":"One of the ugliest dogs I’ve ever met"
    }
]}
```

how could I get the names of keys? (nombre, animal, breed, note)
I was trying of this way, but it doesn't work:

```
for (key in datos) {
                HtmlT += "<td>" + datos.animales[key]+ "</td>"; // it should return nombre
            }
```

datos.animales[key] return undefind

Comment: <obligatory>That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object initializer.</obligatory>

Answer (score 1):

The names you've listed aren't properties of `datos`, they're properties of the entries in the `animales` array. So you have to loop through the `animales` array, and for each entry, use `for-in` to loop through that entry's property names.

```
var animales, index, entry;

animales = datos.animales;
for (index = 0; index < animales.length; ++index) {
    entry = animales[index];
    for (key in entry) {
        // Here, `key` will have the names `"nombre"`, `"animal"`, etc.
    }
}
```

Or in an ES5-enabled environment or if you use an ES5 shim:

```
dataos.animales.forEach(function(entry) {
    var key;

    for (key in entry) {
        // Here, `key` will have the names `"nombre"`, `"animal"`, etc.
    }
});
```

Note that the property names may not be the same for all entries (although of course, they may be if that's how your data is defined).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (key in datos.animales[0]) { HtmlT += "" + datos.animales[0][key]+ ""; }
```

This is the actual element you are looking for.

You might want to loop over the datos array

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
for(var index in datos.animales){
    var animal = datos.animales[i];
    for(var prop in animal){
      console.log(prop+":"+animal[prop]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
for (key in datos) {
  for (animal in datos[key]) {
    HtmlT+= "\"" + animal + "\"";
  }
}
```

when doing a for-each type loop the `key` is the actual key and `object[key]` will return the value.

Comment: [Don't use `for-in` on arrays without safeguards](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)